# ASP.NET: DropDownList onIndexChanged Event Not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a webpage inheriting a masterpage, The webpage has a DropDownList (DDL) in it, with an `OnIndexChanged` Event attached to it.

The problem simply is that the event is not firing, even though a callback occurs (and `page_load()` events are called)..

I did some searching and read that having the page's `viewstate` set to false, would cause a similar issue, and checking the Masterpage (i dont have access to modify it though) i found it set to false, would that be the reason ?

Also is it possible to set the `viewstate = true` on the webpage (the inheriting page) ? would it override the original `viewstate = false` on the master page?

**EDIT :**

The DDL  is shown (using Ajax) when a button is a clicked , so initially (on Page_load() `DDL.visible = false` , but in the `button_click()` event i set `DDL.visible = true` which also populates a datareader that gets bound to the DDL .

Comment: How exactly do you use Ajax? Is your DDL in an update panel?

Comment: yes it is ..(filler) , when the button is clicked i send an asynchronous call to the server to retrieve some data , and tell it to edit the DDL! , and it works.. but when i change the index of the DDL , it performs a callback without firing the event!

Answer (score 2):

Is the DDL's AutoPostBack property set to true?

Answer (score 1):

Do you perform a manually Databind() in the Page_Load() Method? In that case the OnIndexChanged Event will get lost. (Therefore the solution would be not to bind on postback)

**Edit** (after question clarification): I think a PostBackTrigger will help you to the desired solution.

Comment: i do the binding on a button click , is that the same? and should i add something like ` DDLName.OnindexChanged += DDLOnIndexChanged ` ?

Comment: Is the DDL fixed in your markup? Then I do recommend using eventhandler stuff in the markup. Add OnIndexChanged="DLLOnIndexChanged" as property to your DDL. Ensure that the "AutoWireUpEvent" property of the page is set to true.

Comment: yes , sadly still doesnt work :S , found another ` viewstate=false ` on the UpdatePanel itself (i am maintaining the code) , after removing it the page work fine now,BUT everytime i press the button that performs the binding, the DDL  gets updated again and the items doubled..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few obvious things to check. The following 3 things must be setup correctly for yo your page in the page directive at the top of the page.

```
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default"
```

Next in the `<asp:DropDownList` control markup all of these attributes are required to be filled out

```
ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

Then finally you must have a corresponding handler for the event in your code behind

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

If all those things are true the only thing that could stop the page from posting on a change in the selected index is some javascript that returns false on a post request.

If none of these help make a new page and copy and paste your code to it, then build and run again.

Comment: I already checked on all of these, i even tried to re-write the event handler in many different ways.